# Dual Boot: Can the disabled tools be re-enabled after dual boot is completed?

Tags: linux, dual-boot, uefi, manjaro, intel

I'm a little new to linux. I notice on some dual boot tutorials they'll ask you to disable several things in order to proceed with the dual boot steps. For example, if you have Windows pre-installed (UEFI system), you can be asked to disable the following:

- Disable Intel Optane memory
- Disable RAID option
- Enable AHCI
- Disable Secure Boot
- Disable Fast Boot
- Disable CSM (Legacy/MBR) boot

So my question is, can you re-enable some of these things again on your Windows boot after the dual boot is complete? Or will this cause problems for Linux? I'd especially like to know about the Intel Optane memory.

Answer (score 1):

- Disable Intel Optane memory : No need to be disabled. It's a technology that is well supported in Linux. In any case, something makes me think that you do not have such devices ;)
- Disable RAID option : if your computer only has one disk you do not need to enable it and its use is usually discouraged under linux.
- Enable AHCI : compliant option with almost any SO.
- Disable Secure Boot : enabling it can bring you in trouble.
- Disable Fast Boot : The objective of this option is to know what is happening and allow enough time to press the keys to access the different boot menus ( no need to be disabled)
- Disable CSM (Legacy/MBR) boot : no need to be disabled if your linux is installed with UEFI support.

Comment: Reason I ask is because I'm using an Intel Optane M.2 2280 32GB PCIe NVMe 3.0. I'm just one of those people who waste a ton of money without knowing everything first.

Answer (score 0):

My favourite website on this matter is [rodsbooks](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/), in particular the "[UEFI bootloader principles](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/principles.html)" page.

Knowing nothing about problems with Optane and Linux (at all or regarding UEFI), I can note that:

- "RAID" in BIOS/UEFI can only be FakeRAID and any person valuing their data is basically going to avoid it anyways (for potentially unknown/incompatible on-disk data format);
- "AHCI" is the most performant/compatible mode for a typical onboard SATA controller nowadays;
- "Secure Boot" means you either get limited to distros which went through [this pain](http://en.altlinux.org/UEFI_SecureBoot_mini-HOWTO) or you get to mess with your own machine owner keys;
- "Fast boot" can hurt one's ability to even interact with firmware;
- "CSM" can trick some distros into installing in non-UEFI mode (booting with BIOS is enough) which will bring pains of switching modes given dualboot system (or worse).